# omit columns and values in my insert query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert a row into my table X which is made of columns A, B and C.

How can I do an `insert into X (A, B) values (NULL, 'hello');` without getting an error? I get an error when I don't include column C.

I'm omitting the third column in the SQL query and A is an id auto increment.

Is there a way to only insert the first two columns and later do an update for the third column?

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: Please share your SQL to build up your table. It depends, if there are fields NOT NULL, UNIQUE, and so on.. please share your SQL script to build your table!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure the error you are getting, so this is half-guess.

Most likely, your `C` column is set to `NOT NULL` and has no `DEFAULT` value.  Which means it needs to be populated at time of insert.  If you want to skip setting it's value on initial insert you'll need to either give a default value for the column, or allow it to be nullable.

Also, if you want column A to populate it's auto-inc value, you'll need to leave it out of the insert, instead of trying to set the value to NULL

Answer (score 2):

If column C is defined as not null and has no default value defined then you have to include it in your insert.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ColumnC` likely isn't nullable.

Make it nullable with this ALTER command (I've assumed int here, but use the datatype for ColumnC):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY ColumnC int NULL;
```

Once this is done, you can then exclude ColumnC from your `INSERT` statement, and issue an `UPDATE` later.

Answer (score 1):

Try 
INSERT INTO X (B) VALUES ('hello');

You don't need to insert anything into column A since the DB will insert a right value in it (since its auto increment). Hope column C is nullable.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO X(A,B,C)
VALUES
(NULL, 'hello', '');
```

Or you can modify column C and allow it to be null. By doing this, you can do the following,

```
INSERT INTO X(A,B)
VALUES
(NULL, 'hello');
```